# CakePHP Cakemenu plugin fails after global error due to incorrect string encoding

Tags: cakephp, character-encoding, eval

I am using CakePHP 2.1.2 with PHP 5.3.5 and a plugin called 'Cakemenu' which normally works fine.  The plugin stores menus in a db table with the menu link stored as text like

```
array('plugin'=>null,'controller'=>'assets','action'=>'index');
```

The helper in the plugin gets those values, then executes this code to convert that text to an array:

```
    //Try to evaluate the link (if starts with array)
    if (eregi('^array', $value['Menu']['link'])) {
      $code = "\$parse = " . $value['Menu']['link'] . ";";
      $result = eval($code);
      if (is_array($parse)) {
        $value['Menu']['link'] = $parse;
      }
    }
```

Everything works fine unless CakePHP is handling an error. For example if I mistype the name of a controller in the browser I should get a menu and then the missing controller message.  Instead I get a page full "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in..." messages pointing to the line with the eval statement.  If I printout the variable that is getting eval'ed I see that it has been (incorrectly) encoded with Html entities when it normally does not.

Good string to be eval'ed:

```
 $parse = array('plugin'=>null,'controller'=>'assets','action'=>'index');
```

Bad string to be eval'ed:

```
 $parse = array(&#039;plugin&#039;=>null,&#039;controller&#039;=>&#039;Parts&#039;,&#039;action&#039;=>&#039;add&#039;);
```

To temporarily fix the problem I added two statements to just replace the offending characters

```
    $value['Menu']['link'] = str_replace( '&#039;','\'',$value['Menu']['link']);
    $value['Menu']['link'] = str_replace( '&gt;','>',$value['Menu']['link']);
```

and everything works great again.  Some other pieces of information that might be helpful is that the array of data used to generate the menu is read during the beforeFilter of the app and saved in a view variable and then the menu is generated as an element in the view.

I'm thinking that the error causes CakePHP (or PHP) to skip some loading or configuration process and that causes the string to be mishandled. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Using eval is not a good idea, as I'm sure you've heard. Is it possible to contribute to the plugin and use `serialize()` and `unserialize()` instead?

Comment: Probably, but I didn't write the plugin, Nik Chankov did.  I updated it for CakePHP 2, but otherwise it is the original.  The only advantage to the current design is that I can manually edit the database because the array is stored as text.  I could also just write a parsing routine, probably wouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

Your `beforeFilter()` method won't be executed on error pages. You'll have to handle your errors yourself and manually call `beforeFilter()`. I wrote a [blog post](http://www.hoffsays.com/2012/06/12/custom-404-not-found-error-pages-in-cakephp-2-0/) on how to use custom error pages - pay close attention to the **Controller Callbacks** section.

Comment: The before filter is where the data is read so it is getting executed, maybe older versions of CakePHP did not.  I double checked just by adding a comment and it works.  The issue is that the data read and then stored in the view variable has the encoded special characters instead of plain text.  But I think you are on the right track that something is not getting executed or loaded when an error occurs.  Thanks